# C# value type with dynamic number of fields

Tags: c#, value-type

The best way to explain my problem is with a code snippet:

```
enum Resource { ..., Size }
class ResourceVector 
{
    int[] values = new int[(int)Resource.Size];

    public static ResourceVector operator + (ResourceVector a, ResourceVector b)
    {...}

    ...
}
```

We are using this type everywhere as though it were a value type.  I.e. we are making the assumption that:

```
ResourceVector b = a;
b += c;
```

will not affect `a`, because that is how we are used to talking about vectors (and that is how a vector with a fixed number of fields does behave, if implemented as a struct).

However since that assumption is wrong, it has led to some extremely subtle bugs.

I am wondering if there is a way to make this behave as a value type, other than just expanding the members of `Resource` each into their own members in a `struct ResourceVector` (which requires touching every member of `ResourceVector` if we wish to add another `Resource`).

Oh, just in case, we are working with C# 2.0.  So no fancy-pants features :-)

Thanks.

Comment: Make it immutable?  http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/16/immutability-in-c.aspx

Comment: This kind of looks like you're trying to make a flags enum?  If so, just do that instead of this :)  IF not, just mark as struct, pass the values into a ctor, expose them as a read-only collection (or return a copy of the actual array), and off-hand I'd say you're fine (make sure it's immutable once the ctor is done :)

Comment: so if the struct you need, why not just turn it into struct and have your operator methods return new instance instead of modifying existing one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing “value type” with “immutable type”. You actually want your ResourceVector to be an *immutable type*.

An immutable type is one that has no way to change its contents. Once constructed, an instance retains its value until it is garbage-collected. All operations such as addition return a *new instance* containing the result instead of modifying an existing instance.

`string` is the most well-known immutable class. All operations like `Substring` and `Replace` return a *new* string and don’t modify the existing strings.

Once your type is properly immutable, semantically it doesn’t matter so much anymore whether it is a value type or a reference type — but it matters to the performance. If you pass values around a lot, you should probably make it a reference type in order to avoid a lot of unnecessary copying.

Comment: For some reason I thought that wouldn't work with `+=`.  But it turns out it's fine.  (This is very embarrassing, as I am a Haskell programmer.  *What do you mean immutable?*  :-P)